# Galois correspondence, lattice structure

Tags: galois-theory, lattice-orders

I'm new here! I'm studying Galois correspondence and i decided to take confidence with lattice structures (which I've never studied before). I want to ask you this question... given a field $E$ and the group Aut$(E)$, imagine that $\Phi$ is a map from the lattice subgroups of Aut$(E)$ to the lattice subfields of $E$ such that $\Phi(H)=E^H$ for all $H\in$ Aut$(E)$.
Denoting with the symbol $H\vee K$ the smallest subgroup of Aut$(E)$ that contains both $H$ and $K$, and with $H\wedge K$ the biggest subgroup of Aut$(E)$ contained in both $H$ and $K$ (and using the same notation also for th lattice of subfields...), then is it true that $\Phi$ is an anti-homomorphism of lattice i.e. $\Phi(H\vee K)=\Phi(H)\wedge \Phi(K)$ and $\Phi(H\wedge K)=\Phi(H)\vee \Phi(K)$ ??
All I've done is this:

1. If $K\subset H$ then $\Phi(H)\subset \Phi(K)$.
   Proof: If $b\in\Phi(H)=E^H=\{a\in E\ |\ \sigma(a)=a\ $for all $\sigma\in H\}$, then $\sigma(b)=b$ per ogni $\sigma\in K$, hence $b\in \Phi(K)=E^K$.

2. Hence if $H,K\subset H\vee K$ then $\Phi(H\vee K)\subset \Phi(H),\Phi(K)$, so for sure $\Phi(H\vee K)\subset \Phi(H)\wedge \Phi(K)$. What can we say about the inverse inclusion? Is it true or it is just my wrong supposition?
   Thank you to every one that will answer

Comment: You have the right idea and this is the Galois correspondence. Lattices are posets and the inclusions reverse when you move from the field to the group of automorphisms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: Hello @CyclotomicField, thank you for the interest! Yes, i know that under the condition that the extension $E/F$ is a Galois extension of finite degree there is an anti-isomorphism between the lattices of intermediate fields in $E/F$ and the subgroup of Gal$(E/F)$, but what happens in my case in which i use the same functions between lattices but i don't consider (intentionally) Galois extensions and its corresponding Galois group, but i  simply consider $E$ and Aut$(E)$?

Comment: Take any set and consider all of its subsets. They form a lattice by inclusion with a maximal element being the whole set and minimal element the empty set. So you have a lot of freedom to consider sublattices of that general construction.